# Tricky css/javascript floating task

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position, css-float

I have a design that has several divs at varying widths/heights and I need them to float essentially to the top left. A simple css float:left will not work because it does not take advantage of the vertical space once it drops to a new line.

I assume I will need to use jQuery to dynamically position each div but I was hoping someone could lead me in the right direction.

This is what a standard float left would do:
[standard float http://www.media1designs.com/poc/superfloat/diagram_float_left.gif](http://www.media1designs.com/poc/superfloat/diagram_float_left.gif)

This is what I need it to do:
[what I need http://www.media1designs.com/poc/superfloat/diagram.gif](http://www.media1designs.com/poc/superfloat/diagram.gif)

The sizes of the divs will change as the website's content updates so manually entering the positions is not an option.

Comment: Todd, I believe the div's are display in block by default. Would setting the divs to display: inline would solve your problem?

Comment: @nolabel: No, I've tried inline and inline-block. Neither give the right result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [masonry plugin](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an algorithm for determining where to place the next element given a set of existing elements and a bounding box (the container width & height). I'd start with plain english and just writing it down with pen and paper first - it's easier than code.

Once you have that, you'll use the jQuery `width` and `height` functions to get the sizes of the elements to position and I believe you'll want the `css` function for setting the `top`/`left`. The `position` of the elements should be `"absolute"` and the `position` of the containing element should be `"relative"`. See all [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/) methods.

Assuming you've written your layout algorithm as the function `calculateOffset(element, container)` returning an offset literal (e.g. `{left: x, top: y}`) and that you have a jQuery element list `elements` and a jQuery-wrapped `container`, you can do something like this to position everything:

```
elements.each(function() {
  $(this).css(calculateOffset($(this), container));
});
```

The hard part, of course, is writing `calculateOffset`. For that I recommend starting with something simple, like finding the highest possible (lowest `top`) place to put an element, favoring the left side (lowest `left`), then going from there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I've ever heard of or seen a layout engine that would display things in that fashion.  Most likely, you'll just have to write it yourself.

You'll need to create an API (at least in the way you think of things).  Most likely, you'll end up with a Block (each div to be laid out) and a Container (the area holding the divs).  Apply the appropriate methods, properties, and *events* to each of them, and you'll probably get there rather quickly.