# Multi-column Floated Divs Row Issue

Tags: jquery, css

I need a primarily css or js way to have div floats on a different row drop into the excess height, bad description, I know. Here is a example: http://jsfiddle.net/aPwtR/1/

A good example is this: http://blog.xlune.com/2009/09/vgrid/demo003.html (It uses absolute positioning and jQuery)

Anyone know of a standalone jQuery plugin or a css solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521319/tricky-css-javascript-floating-task/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for your problem is [jQuery Masonry](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/) a jQuery plugin by David DeSandro.